# code to parse JSON works in IntelliJ but doesn't work in android studio

Tags: android, json

There is a JSON posted on a website that I'm trying to read and pull back into an android app notification.

JSON String in question:
{"fridgestatus": "fail", "fridedetail": [{"unit": "zxcv", "name": "Chill Wall #2", "readtime": "2018-06-05T16:57:00.789000Z", "TempF": 27.14}, {"unit": "asdf", "name": "Chill Wall #3", "readtime": "2018-06-05T17:41:08.961000Z", "TempF": 37.22}, {"unit": "qwer", "name": "Chill Wall #1", "readtime": "2018-06-05T17:30:50.822000Z", "TempF": 33.98}, {"unit": "tyui", "name": "Back Room ", "readtime": "2018-06-05T18:34:52.605000Z", "TempF": 49.46}, {"unit": "ghjk", "name": "Chill Wall #5", "readtime": "2018-06-05T18:23:17.123000Z", "TempF": 36.68}]}

This is hosted on a URL somewhere.

Here is my code in Java:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        String fridge = "All fridges are normal";

            fridge = getFridge();
            System.out.print(fridge);

    }

    public static String getText(String url) throws Exception {
        URL website = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),"UTF8"));

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            response.append(inputLine);

        in.close();

        return response.toString();
    }

     public static JSONObject parser() throws Exception{


        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(getText("WEB URL"));

        return json;
    }

    public static String getFridge() throws Exception{
        String thisFridge = "No issues.";

        JSONObject json = parser();

        JSONArray n = json.getJSONArray("fridgedetail");
        for (int i=0; i<n.length(); i++){
            JSONObject m = n.getJSONObject(i);
            if(m.getDouble("TempF")>40.00)
                thisFridge = m.getString("name");

        }


        return thisFridge;
    }




}
```

However when I try to pull this into android to make a notification when the temp is too high the app just crashes.

Android code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
        public void notification(View view) throws Exception
        {

            addNotification();
        }
        private void addNotification() throws Exception
        {
            String fridge = "All fridges are normal";

            fridge = getFridge();

            String temp = "All temperatures are normal";
            temp = getTemp();


            NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"notify_001")

                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.message)
                            .setContentTitle(fridge)   //this is the title of notification
                            .setColor(101)
                            .setContentText(temp);   //this is the message showed in notification

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            // Add as notification
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("notify_001",
                        "Channel human readable title",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
            manager.notify(0, builder.build());
        }
    public static String getText(String url) throws Exception {
        URL website = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),"UTF8"));

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            response.append(inputLine);

        in.close();

        return response.toString();
    }

     public static JSONObject parser() throws Exception{




        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(getText(WEB URL));

        return json;
    }

    public static String getFridge() throws Exception{
        String thisFridge = "No issues.";

        JSONObject json = parser();

        JSONArray n = json.getJSONArray("fridgedetail");
        for (int i=0; i<n.length(); i++){
            JSONObject m = n.getJSONObject(i);
            if(m.getDouble("TempF")>40.00)
                thisFridge = m.getString("name");

        }


        return thisFridge;
    }
    public static String getTemp() throws Exception{
        String tempIs = "Temperature is normal";
        return tempIs;
    }

}
```

Comment: You really do not want to use GSON instead of a custom implementation ?

Comment: Where are you calling `notification()`?

Comment: notification() is called on a button attached to the app on the XML page.